# Is there a better way to space ChartLabels?

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts, version-12.1

I am looking for a better way to specify the spacing between `ChartLabels` when using BarChart. My current implementation uses `Riffle` and `Splice` (new in version 12.1) to splice empty strings into a list of dates. The labels could be anything, but I'm working with dates. For this example, I've created an arbitrary list of numbers for the `BarChart` data.

My method works, but I'm wondering if I'm missing some option/technique that could be better. Here's my working code:

```
dayInc = 5;
dateRng = DateRange[DateObject[{2020, 2, 1}], Today, Quantity[dayInc, "Days"]];
dateStr = Riffle[
   Map[DateString[#, {"MonthShort", "/", "DayShort", "/", "YearShort"}] &][dateRng],
        Splice[Table["", {dayInc - 1}]]
   ];
data = Range[Length[dateStr]];

BarChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[dateStr, Below, Rotate[#1, 60 Degree] &]]
```

[image: BarChart]